# How to pass-through mouse in Hyper-V?

Tags: hyper-v, hypervisor, hyper-v-manager

I want my mouse to stay in the guest machine until I press a hotkey.

I have looked through hundreds of questions, articles and guides about this, but I only encounter failures. One of them is RemoteFX, I came across [another question similar to this](https://superuser.com/q/849918/167207) and repeated what is written in the instruction, but my mouse just doesn't work.

I just want my mouse to stay on the Hyper-V guest machine and never exit it until I press the hotkey. I have a lot of virtual machines.

What do I need to do to make it work. Will the PS/2 mouse help me? Perhaps there is a program or script that will prohibit the cursor from exiting the Hyper-V guest machine.

At the moment, working with Hyper-V, I can't do this. There is such a function in VMware Workstation, but I need Hyper-V.

How do I make sure that my mouse always stays in the guest machine until I press the hotkey?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [capture real mouse input Hyper-V](https://superuser.com/questions/1559072/capture-real-mouse-input-hyper-v)

Comment: @harrymc No. This is absolutely not what I need. I need my mouse to always stay in the VM until I press a hotkey to pass it to the host. Neither advanced mode nor remotefx solve my problem. I thought maybe pass-through the mouse would help me with that, but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not a function written in to any of the Hyperv console or remote desktop tools provided by Microsoft.

You could find an equivalent method by running your RD session full screen.

It is also possible that there are 3rd party tools that offer this function.

Comment: I know that there is no such problem in fullscreen mode, but I have a lot of virtual machines and it is inconvenient for me to switch each virtual machine every time. Do you know a place where you can find a person who can make such a tool for money? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: No, and that question is very off topic here.